# NodeJS Express: sending reqeust after rendering page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I saw this code snippet on geeksforgeeks for rendering an html page with routing system.

Here's the simple code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
 
// View engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 
// With middleware
app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('User')
    next();
});
 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Render Working")
    res.send();
});
 
app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```

But there's something really weird about this code:
Invoking res.send() after res.render() has been invoked. What's happening?
Isn't res.render() already sending data to the client socket and closing the stream? So that res.send() call really has no effect since the connection gets closed after res.render call?

Here's another really weird looking scenario

Ignore the details of this snippet, but focus instead of what happens when the client does a get request to a server implemented like this:

```js
app.get('/verify_email', function(req,res) {
    console.log('verify_email token: ',req.query.token);

    User.findOne({ authToken: req.query.token }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }
        console.dir(user);

        user.isAuthenticated = true;
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log('succesfully updated user');
            console.log(user);

            res.send(user);
        });
    });

    res.render('index', {title: 'Authenticating...'});
});
```

two calls that really make me feel uneasy are:

```js
res.render('index', {title: 'Authenticating...'});
```

and after the callback of findOne:

```js
res.send(user);
```

But again, a request can contain only one response, once the client gets the body it cannot wait for other messages since by definition of the http protocol when keep alive is not enabled connections do not stay alive.

So why is he sending the data for the html page, and then to the same stream and presumably the same client socket, he executes the res.send(user); instruction? At the time of that callback invocation, shouldn't the connection be already closed?

You can find the first and second snippet respectively on these websites:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-render-function/

https://sendgrid.com/blog/double-opt-email-node-js/

Comment: no res.render etc does not stop the next middlewares firing, and you cannot send multiple responses, you should be getting errors.

Comment: You get errors on the _server_, but not on the _client_. The client is satisfied with the first response sent by `res.render()`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone funny thing is I don't get errors if I leave the send call without parameters. But If I add parameters to the call I get an error, and that makes sense to me. It doesn't make sense to me not getting errors when res.send() without parameters is invoked.

Comment: Can you link your sources please? Notice that there's always the possibility that random code examples found on the internet are simply wrong.

Comment: @Bergi https://sendgrid.com/blog/double-opt-email-node-js/

Look for the string "Update the verify_email route next. Change it to:" with CTRL+F

Comment: To me, it seems like they just did "forget" to remove the `res.render('index', {title: 'Authenticating...'});` line they had previously in that route when they wanted you to update it. And that code has several other problems, like `if (err) return console.error(err);` never sending a response to the client.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I saw that too, I have my own server so I wasn't just going to blindly copy and paste code found online. Lord if the internet is full of broken code.